# How to use Perl grep on a hash instead of an array?

Tags: perl

I'm learning Perl. I have been able to use `grep` on an array and the syntax is very simple, like this [example](https://perlmaven.com/filtering-values-with-perl-grep):

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @names = qw(Foo Bar Baz);
my $visitor = <STDIN>;
chomp $visitor;
if (grep { $visitor eq $_ } @names) {
   print "Visitor $visitor is in the guest list\n";
} else {
   print "Visitor $visitor is NOT in the guest list\n";
}
```

However, I would like to know if there is an equally simple way to use `grep` on a hash **without coding a loop to iterate through each item in the hash**.

Here is some example data with the structure I'm working with. Before assigning a URI, I want to check if any item has that uri value already. For example, **I want to assign `ww1.example.com` to item `v2rbz1568`, but only if no other item has a uri value of `ww1.example.com`. How can I efficiently accomplish that in Perl?**

```
{
    "0y7vfr1234": {
        "username": "user1@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password123",
        "uri": "ww1.example.com",
        "index": 14
    },
    "v2rbz1568": {
        "username": "user3@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password125",
        "uri": "ww3.example.com",
        "index": 29
    },
    "0zjk1156": {
        "username": "user2@example.com",
        "password": "some-random-password124",
        "uri": "ww2.example.com",
        "index": 38
    }
}
```

I'm using perl 5, version 30 on Linux.

Comment: you can of course use grep with values: `grep { ... } values %$hash_ref`. Your question has nothing to do with Unix and is too basic to be useful (you could've gathered that and more with a simple search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least two options:

1. You have (only) the data structure you visioned in your question. Then you will have to iterate through the whole "list" every time you want to find a match. You don't have to write a loop though, you can use the `map` function:

```perl
use strict; use warnings;
my %entries = (
    '0y7vfr1234' => {
        'username' => 'user1@example.com',
        'password' => 'some-random-password123',
        'uri' => 'ww1.example.com',
        'index' => 14
    },
    'v2rbz1568' => {
        'username' => 'user3@example.com',
        'password' => 'some-random-password125',
        'uri' => 'ww3.example.com',
        'index' => 29
    }
);
my $uri = <STDIN>;
chomp $uri;
if (grep { $uri eq $_ } map { $_->{'uri'} } values %entries) {
   print "URI $uri is in the list\n";
} else {
   print "URI $uri is NOT in the list\n";
}
```

2. You manage a separate index into the hash so that you can do quick lookups. An index means you have a separate hash mapping URIs to the items of the actual hash:

```perl
use strict; use warnings;
my %entries = (
    '0y7vfr1234' => {
        'username' => 'user1@example.com',
        'password' => 'some-random-password123',
        'uri' => 'ww1.example.com',
        'index' => 14
    },
    'v2rbz1568' => {
        'username' => 'user3@example.com',
        'password' => 'some-random-password125',
        'uri' => 'ww3.example.com',
        'index' => 29
    }
);
my %index = map { $entries{"uri"} => $_ } keys %entries;

my $uri = <STDIN>;
chomp $uri;
my $item = $index{$uri};
if (defined($item)) {
   print "URI $uri is in the list\n";
} else {
   print "URI $uri is NOT in the list\n";
}
```

This is also convenient in that you get the `$item` directly as a result of the lookup, if you want to access the already-existing entry in the hash in addition to just checking whether it exists, e.g. `print "Index: ",$entries{$item}->{'index'},"\n";`

In this second case you'll have to update the index manually every time you add/update/delete URIs in the "list":

```perl
$entries{"v84x9v8b9"} = { uri => "ww49", ... };
$index{"ww49"} = "v84x9v8b9";
```